# custom char for bulletlist sphinx

Tags: html, css, customization, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

There is someway to change the the default bullet 'disc'/'circle' on sphinx ? i tried something like the solution from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sphinx-users/fNWyyRzoa8I but it doesn't work for me, possibly because i'm not familiar with html and css syntax.

_static/custom.css:

```
ul.squarelist {                     
    list-style-type: square;  
    margin-left: 0;            
    padding-left: 0;           
}                              
li.squarelist {                     
    padding-left: 1em;         
    text-indent: -1em;         
}
```

test.rst:

```
.. cssclass:: squarelist    

    * foo             
    * bar
```

output -> test.html:

```
<ul class="check simple">           
<li>foo</li>                                
<li>bar</li>                   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  Here's the code you want.

_static/custom.css (li.squarelist is unnecessary):

```
ul.squarelist {
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

test.rst (note correct directive and proper indentation):

```
.. rst-class:: squarelist

* foo
* bar
```

Yields:

```
<ul class="squarelist simple">
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works on the default theme, but not in the read the docs (sphinx_rdt_theme). Any idea why ?

Comment: Does the HTML render the same? Did you spell the theme correctly (you transposed the "t" and "d")? Does your `custom.css` get copied on RTD or is it missing and return a 404? Do you have an example somewhere online that you can share for further examination?