# In Sphinx, is it possible to have a lowercase alphabet list (a., b., c., etc.) instead of (or subordinate to) a numbered list (1., 2., 3., etc.)?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'd like to have an ordered list that uses lowercase letters of the alphabet rather than numerals. I'd especially like to do this as a list that is subordinate to a list that uses numerals:

```
1. Blah

2. Blah

3. Blah

  a. Blah

  b. Blah
```

Is this possible in Sphinx?

I went to https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html, but couldn't find anything.

I've used #'s and indented #'s, but it just uses numerals for everything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use auto-enumerator in nested lists (reStructuredText)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906849/how-to-use-auto-enumerator-in-nested-lists-restructuredtext)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

a) use custom CSS for consistent "numbering" of all enumerated lists.

b) indicate the number style on the first item of the (sub) list. Following items may be auto-numbered. Cf. the [Docutils HTML output example](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/test/functional/expected/standalone_rst_html5.html#enumerated-lists).

The following works in plain Docutils:

```
#. Outer list

   a. nested list
   
   #. with alphabetical markers
   
#. second item outer list
```